# Finding locations with the closest coordinates in google maps(out of a set of given ones) relative to current user's location

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am creating a kind of ebay like website only with services. All the provided services come with google maps lat/lang coordinates. In it there is supposed to be a functionality to find all the services in a 10 mile radius of the current user's location.

What I have in this page is an array of all the services in the website's locations(lat/lang) and **need to get the current user's location and find all the services whose lat/lang coordinates place them in a 10 mile radius of the user's location.**

**Example:** there are 3 barbers in New York in the website. A user located in the outskirts of the city enters the website and wants to find a barber. Only one of the 3 is located in a 10 mile radius of the user's location and only that one shows up.

**Clarification:** the idea isn't to search for all sorts of service providers out of google maps's database, it's to search only in the coordinates I have provided on my page. Also in the page there is no actual map it's more like a classic search page - user clicks "find services near me" and after google maps has told me which of the ones are nearby I show them as text only.

*If something in my question is unclear please notify me and I'll correct it as fast as possible.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar but on a large scale, thought might not be the most efficient maybe it will give you an insight or better idea of what to do.

what you need to do is look for the great circle distance, theres an algorithm for it you can find online. this algorithm takes two sets of coordinates (the two you want to compare), and gets the distance, i basically looped through all the locations and find the shortest distance and thats the closest.

Comment: To be honest I was thinking of something like this but was first trying to make sure there isn't some easy ready to use google maps api function that just inputs 2 sets of coordinates and calculates their distance. Thanks for the great circle distance formula as it sped up my research quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [GeoHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) and a trie data structure. Redis has a feature built in to achieve these spatial queries with radius.

Each and every coordinate where you want to search, can be stored as geohash in a trie. Then based on the search lat/long, calculate its GeoHash and start going 3-4 levels deep in the trie (or as the distance mentions). Then display all the nodes below that node of the trie.